# Range value not shown in locals window in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, range

I was wondering why there is no value property for range object listed in locals window. The value2 is listed there. At the same time I use the Range.Value in the code and it works ok:

```
Set Rng = Range("D6:D9")
Set Rng2 = Range("B2:B5")
Rng2.Value = Rng.Value
```

Does it mean that excel stores Range values by default in value2? I'm just curious how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `.Value` property is not listed separately in the debug windows as since Office version 2007, an optional argument was added and from experience with writing object code via class modules, only properties without arguments are listed in the locals window. Another property that would be very useful to have shown would be: `.Address` but again this has multiple optional arguments so i believe it's for this reason it's not listed. `.Value2` on the other hand takes no arguments and so does appear in the locals window.

The optional argument is listed in MS Help as: `.Value(RangeValueDataType)` where `RangeValueDataType` takes one of the enumeration values:

```
xlRangeValueDefault     
xlRangeValueMSPersistXML
xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet
```

But perhaps you missed that `.Value` *does appear at the top level in the Local/Watch window in grey* (as shown)? This is because `.Value(xlRangeValueDefault)` is the default value of `Range`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a logical explanation. Regarding value shown at top, I see that it is indeed shown in the Waches window, but only as long as the range is a single cell. For the range consisting of multiple cells only Value2 is shown as an array.

Comment: Yes you're correct the default value is only shown when Range consists of a single cell. `Value2` is in a sense the native Excel value and is faster to access presumably as it does not have to read the formatted number of the cell only the underlying value.