# Why don't an Application's Addins, Columns or Rows properties appear in the Locals Window?

Tags: vba, excel, properties, typelib, objectbrowser

How come an `Excel.Application` reference shows the `Addins2` property in Locals Window, but not the `Addins` property? Ditto `Columns` and `Rows` properties? Is that some host-specific TLB hack for the Locals Window, or are those members marked in some way?

They're not hidden, they're not functions and they're not indexers, so why doesn't the Locals Window show them?

There may be other properties that aren't present, but `AddIns`, `Columns` and `Rows` are the ones that I noticed were missing.

Comment: Aren't columns and rows properties of the Worksheet member, and not of the application? Edit: Nevermind, they dont appear within the worksheet member either.

Comment: This may shed some light on the problem (I dont know the object model well enough to say if this answers the question for certain though): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643876/range-value-not-shown-in-locals-window-in-excel-vba .

Comment: open the _Watch window_. right click in Watch window ... Add watch ... put the word _application_ in the expression ... choose _(all procedures)_ and _(all modules)_ (**very important** otherwise you have to have be at a breakpoint to see the object properties)... press ok.  click the "+" on the _Application_ line that shows up. that is the application object properties and method tree.  ......... do same with objects like _activesheet_ and _addins_